# WebBrowser load and display URLs from file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I want to load a list of URLs in a text file. I have done that using a `For Each` loop, but I want the browser to load the page first fully before going to the next URL. Here is my code:

```
For Each url in File.ReadAllLines("urls.txt")
    Browser.Navigate(url)
Next
```

It doesn't display anything. I tried using:

```
Do While Browser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()
Loop
```

It displays the page but the first line is the only one being loaded.

Comment: hey @Gerard Balaoro, will they need to be opened in another WB tabbed window or just load and then go to the next URL?

Comment: what do you think about telling it to wait 5 seconds until looping again?

Comment: @Werdna Its my temporary solution. But the net speed varies and it depends on the site. I need it to adjust automatically

Comment: have a look @ Visual Vincent's answer for you, here is a link its in c# but it have some good examples of waiting for a task to complete :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149811/how-to-wait-for-async-method-to-complete

Comment: @Werdna : Did I just steal your answer? :l

Comment: @VisualVincent : Not at all my friend hahahahahah, In fact, I think your answer is great for it simplicity.

Comment: @Werdna : Good, because I didn't see your comments until after I had written the first version. Though I did copy you a little by explaining how to add a delay.

Comment: @VisualVincent all good mate, here's an up vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to navigate to each URL after the other you are better of storing all of them in a class level array and subscribing to the [**`WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx), then keep track of which URL index you're currently at via a class level `Integer` variable.

When the `DocumentCompleted` event is raised you just increment the integer variable and load the URL from the next item of the array.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim URLs As String()
    Dim UrlIndex As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        URLs = File.ReadAllLines("urls.txt")
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(URLs(UrlIndex))
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        UrlIndex += 1
        If UrlIndex >= URLs.Length Then
            UrlIndex = 0 'Go back to the beginning.
        End If

        WebBrowser1.Navigate(URLs(UrlIndex))
    End Sub
End Class
```

To add a delay to it to make each URL show for a little while you can use a [**`Timer`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) *(Credit to Werdna for bringing up the subject)*:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    UrlIndex += 1
    If UrlIndex >= URLs.Length Then
        UrlIndex = 0 'Go back to the beginning.
    End If

    WebBrowser1.Navigate(URLs(UrlIndex))
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

Just set the timer's [**`Interval` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx) to change how long a site should be displayed (in milliseconds).