# Prevent a timer from restarting until it's async task is done

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer

I thought at first this was going to be just a "[How to wait for async method to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149811/how-to-wait-for-async-method-to-complete)" question.  But, I think it's a little more than that.

I have a timer set up as such...

```
public void Start()
{
    _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    _timer.Interval = _context.adpSettings.SyncInterval * 1000;
    _timer.AutoReset = false;
    _timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = ExecuteTransactionReportAsync();
    _timer.Start(); 
}

private async Task ExecuteTransactionReportAsync()
{
    AccessEvent accessEvent = new AccessEvent();
    ....  do some logic
    await _context.GetConnector().EnqeueuEventAsync(accessEvent);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to NOT have `timer_Elapsed()` fire again until after  `ExecuteTransactionReportAsync()` is done. But, because  `ExecuteTransactionReportAsync()` is async, the process keeps going and  `timer_Elapsed()` will fire again.

In real life, it will never take `ExecuteTransactionReportAsync()` more than 10 seconds to finish it's task. (At least it better not or we have other problems.)  But when I'm debugging, it's a pain.

Is there a simple solution that doesn't involve making `ExecuteTransactionReportAsync()` non async?

Comment: Stop the timer, run the async task, add `ContinueWith` to the task to restart the timer?

Comment: Don't use timer, rather single thread with loop with delay at the end of loop.

Comment: `var t = await ExecuteTransactionReportAsync();` ? You have to make the eventHandler async to use that.

Comment: Little correction: Since it's `async Task ExecuteTransactionReportAsync` , that would have to be without `var t = ` just `await ExecuteTransactionReportAsync()`

Comment: @Fildor, that was the first thing I tried.  But then it forces the call in Start() to change to await as well, and I was having trouble getting that to work

Comment: @Fildor, as per your first comment, that's what I'm not sure how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of TAP is correct, then this should work as intended:

```
private async void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    await ExecuteTransactionReportAsync();
    _timer.Start(); 
}
```

Or what DavidG was suggesting:

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Stop();
    ExecuteTransactionReportAsync().ContinueWith( () => {_timer.Start(); });
}
```

Comment: That works!  I thought I had tried this, but I guess not.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, in my first comment when I said "that works" I was talking about your first example.  Your second example is more what I was originally thinking about, or looking for. But I like your first example better.