# C# Wait for async method to finish before continuing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created this `ViewModel` for my `CollectionView`:

```
public class TemplateListViewModel
{
    public double WidthHeight { get; set; }

    public ICommand LoadTemplates => new Command(MyHandler);
    public int CurrentTemplateCountReceived;
    public bool HitBottomOfList = false;
    public ObservableCollection<TemplateSource> sourceList { get; set; }


    public TemplateListViewModel()
    {
        CurrentTemplateCountReceived = 0;
        sourceList = new ObservableCollection<TemplateSource>();

        var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
        var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;
        var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
        var ScaledWidth = width / density;

        WidthHeight = (ScaledWidth / 2);

        loadingTemplates += onLoadingTemplates;
        LoadTemplateList();
    }

    private event EventHandler loadingTemplates = delegate { };

    private Task LoadTemplateList()
    {
        loadingTemplates(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        return null;
    }

    private async void onLoadingTemplates(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (HitBottomOfList == false)
        {
            List<Template> templateList = await App.RestService.GetTemplates(App.User, CurrentTemplateCountReceived);

            if (templateList != null)
            {
                foreach (var template in templateList)
                {
                    ImageSource source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("mysite.org/myapp/" + template.FileName));
                    TemplateSource templateSource = new TemplateSource { Id = template.Id, Source = source, WidthHeight = WidthHeight, FileName = template.FileName };
                    sourceList.Add(templateSource);
                }

                CurrentTemplateCountReceived = sourceList.Count;
            }
            else
            {
                HitBottomOfList = true;
            }
        }
    }

    bool handling = false;

    public void MyHandler()
    {
        // already handling an event, ignore the new one
        if (handling) return;

        handling = true;

        LoadTemplateList();

        handling = false;
    }
}
```

Now what this does is: It collects image locations from my webpage and then creates the `ImageSources` for those collected images and adds it to the sourceList. Now I also created a `RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadTemplates}"` in the xaml, so it collects more data when it almost hits the bottom of the `CollectionView`, by calling this command: `ICommand LoadTemplates => new Command(MyHandler);`. This event gets fired a lot of times so I created this handler:

```
public void MyHandler()
{
    // already handling an event, ignore the new one
    if (handling) return;

    handling = true;

    LoadTemplateList();

    handling = false;
}
```

That checks if there is already an event being handled.

The problem is that in `MyHandler`, `LoadTemplateList()` doesn't get awaited for result, which results in many calls to my webpage, because `handling` will be set to `false` immediately!

Now how can I await the `LoadTemplateList()`?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149811/how-to-wait-for-async-method-to-complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now how can I await the LoadTemplateList()?

With the `await` keyword:

```
handling = true;

await LoadTemplateList();

handling = false;
```

However, it will still return early, because the code is doing some funky private `EventHandler` stuff. If you just remove all that excess code and move the asynchronous code into `LoadTemplateList`, it will work fine:

```
public class TemplateListViewModel
{
    public double WidthHeight { get; set; }

    public ICommand LoadTemplates => new Command(MyHandler);
    public int CurrentTemplateCountReceived;
    public bool HitBottomOfList = false;
    public ObservableCollection<TemplateSource> sourceList { get; set; }


    public TemplateListViewModel()
    {
        CurrentTemplateCountReceived = 0;
        sourceList = new ObservableCollection<TemplateSource>();

        var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
        var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;
        var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
        var ScaledWidth = width / density;

        WidthHeight = (ScaledWidth / 2);

        MyHandler();
    }

    private async Task LoadTemplateList()
    {
        if (HitBottomOfList == false)
        {
            List<Template> templateList = await App.RestService.GetTemplates(App.User, CurrentTemplateCountReceived);

            if (templateList != null)
            {
                foreach (var template in templateList)
                {
                    ImageSource source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("mysite.org/myapp/" + template.FileName));
                    TemplateSource templateSource = new TemplateSource { Id = template.Id, Source = source, WidthHeight = WidthHeight, FileName = template.FileName };
                    sourceList.Add(templateSource);
                }

                CurrentTemplateCountReceived = sourceList.Count;
            }
            else
            {
                HitBottomOfList = true;
            }
        }
    }

    bool handling = false;

    public async void MyHandler()
    {
        // already handling an event, ignore the new one
        if (handling) return;

        handling = true;

        await LoadTemplateList();

        handling = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `Command` with `CanExecute` with `ChangeCanExecute` as mentioned here in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding)

Also Unsubscribe to events by `-=` before subscribing

And you can make command async and add awaited action as

```cs
Command MyCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteMyCommand());
```

Comment: It doesn't seem that my `onLoadingTemplates` gets called using your code, because I added a breakpoint on the first line, but that doesn't get hit! I added the following to my code: `MyCommand.CanExecute(true);`..... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: initialization of command should have ```CanExecute``` parameter set to a local property. and ExecuteMyCommand signature should be something like ```private async Task ExecuteMyCommand()`{ await ......}```