# Calling async function in synchronous function doesn't wait for it to finish

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm trying to call the async function getLatestTag in a synchronous one, but I can't get the  program to finish for it to execute before continuing.

```
public static void checkInstalled()
{
    var t = new Task(getLatestTag);
    t.Start();
    if (623 == tagOutput)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("succes");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("fail");
    }
}

private static async void getLatestTag()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://api.github.com/repos/Futminer/miner-download/releases/latest");
    var productValue = new ProductInfoHeaderValue("FutMiner", "1.0");
    request.Headers.UserAgent.Add(productValue);
    var resp = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    HttpContent content = resp.Content;
    string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
    tagOutput = Convert.ToInt32(obj["tag_name"]);
}
```

Comment: Short answer: Don't call async code from sync code

Comment: Also: async void is a really bad practice, you should go and learn how async works before continuing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait for async method to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149811/how-to-wait-for-async-method-to-complete)

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. There's no good reason to call `Task.Start` in application code. How is `checkInstalled` called? That method should be asynchronous itself, going all the way to the top-level event handler that started these calls. The event handler should be `async void` but all the other methods should be `async Task`. Calling `.Wait()` will freeze the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Panagiotis Kanavos's advice:

> Tasks aren't threads. There's no good reason to call Task.Start in
> application code. How is checkInstalled called? That method should be
> asynchronous itself, going all the way to the top-level event handler
> that started these calls. The event handler should be async void but
> all the other methods should be async Task. Calling .Wait() will
> freeze the UI

After making every necessary function async and using await when needed I managed to get everything working the way I wanted

Answer (score -2):

First off, never return void from an async method - rather return a Task instance.

Then, if you're certain that you want to handle the async method in a sync method, to force it to wait for the result you need .Result on it.

So your code should be like this:

```
public static void checkInstalled()
{
    getLatestTag().Wait();
    
    if (623 == tagOutput)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("succes");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("fail");
    }
}

private static async Task getLatestTag()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://api.github.com/repos/Futminer/miner-download/releases/latest");
    var productValue = new ProductInfoHeaderValue("FutMiner", "1.0");
    request.Headers.UserAgent.Add(productValue);
    var resp = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    HttpContent content = resp.Content;
    string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
    tagOutput = Convert.ToInt32(obj["tag_name"]);
}
```

Comment: 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no accessible extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to Task<T>. See my edit.

Comment: After running the app it doesn't seem to go past "getLatestTag().Wait();" as it doesn't run the following code

Comment: `Task.Wait` is almost always a bad idea and can lead to deadlocks.