# Questions about multiple tasks in one async function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Here is my code to test the situation with multiple tasks in one async function:

```
class EvaluateAwait
    {
        
        static async Task Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main func: Thread ID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Task task1 = PrintAndWait("1");
            Console.WriteLine("Task 1 created");
            Task task2 = PrintAndWait("2");           
            Console.WriteLine("Task 2 Created");
            await task1; 
            await task2;
            Console.WriteLine("Main Returned.");
        }

        static async Task PrintAndWait(string id)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) { 
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            
                Console.WriteLine("Thread ID:"+ Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " | Task ID:" +id + " | " );
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Thread ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " | Task ID: " + id + "completed");

        }


    }
```

}

My origianl **expecation** for what happens is:

1. Main func prints its thread
2. Main func enters `PrintAndWait` for the first time for `task1`.

   > PrintAndWait returns but not completed,when meeting the first await sentence `await Task.Delay(5000)`.
3. Main func prints "Task 1 created"
4. Main func enters `PrintAndWait` for the second time for `task2`.

   > PrintAndWait returns but not completed,when meeting the first await sentence `await Task.Delay(5000)`
5. `await task1` so task1 should return the awaiter, do its 50 loops to print thread ID every sec.
   **Here comes my quetion**,
   *as `await task1` is the first await sentence in Main, I suppose Main should return    here, which means any of the code after this line, should not be run until task1 is finished. So I am expecting seeing task1 prints the thread info first, then task2 do the printing.*
6. `await task2` so task2 should return the awaiter, do its 50 loops to print thread ID every sec.

But the output is

```
Main func: Thread ID = 1
Task 1 created
Task 2 Created
Thread ID:7 | Task ID:2 |
Thread ID:10 | Task ID:1 |
Thread ID:7 | Task ID:2 |
Thread ID:10 | Task ID:1 |
```

It looks like Task1 and Task2 running simultaneously. Do I have some misunderstandings about the await mechnism?

Comment: " not completed" does NOT mean that is hasn't started. It is running immediately.

Comment: Try moving `await Task.Delay(1000);` below the `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: If you add the line `task1.Wait();` immediately after the line `Console.WriteLine("Task 1 created");`, does it behave as you expected? Does [How to wait for async method to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15151444/1115360) explain it to your satisfaction?

Comment: The continuations may complete on a thread pool thread. If you want synchronous behavior, don't use async.

Comment: You can also immediately await the `PrintAndWait` calls to get about the behavior you are expecting.

Comment: "So I am expecting seeing task1 prints the thread info first, then task2 do the printing." Why do you expect that, because the rest of the main method won't continue until `task1` is finished, that the other work will be unable to continue?  All of the code from that other `PrintAndWait` call isn't in that method after all, so it's not waiting on `task2` to finish.

Comment: You start two asynchronous tasks. They are running independently of each other and you don't have any control over which one is scheduled to continue after each `await Task.Delay(1000)` The only thing guaranteed is, that both task will be finished, once you reach the final `Console.WriteLine("Main Returned")`

Comment: @Fildor and everyone you are right. I had a mistaken impression  that the statemachine of task2 will not run continously if I do not use await.      Meanwhile I try to remove the line "await task2", the output is same as previous, also meaning it is not a must to keep task2 running with await. Thanks everyone for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks like Task1 and Task2 running simultaneously. Do I have some
> misunderstandings about the await mechnism?

As your tests showed, yes you do.

```
Task task1 = PrintAndWait("1");
```

That can start the code right away. When you use `await` it means that now you actually need the result, so "wait" for it.

If the code didn't start right away, what would be the point of:

```
Task task1 = PrintAndWait("1");
Console.WriteLine("Task 1 created");
Task task2 = PrintAndWait("2");           
Console.WriteLine("Task 2 Created");
await task1; 
await task2;
```

instead of?

```
await PrintAndWait("1");
await PrintAndWait("2");
```

Comment: Yes you are right.  I try to remove both "await task1" and "await task2" then replace them with “await Task.Delay(50000)”. The result is the same.  I had wrong impression that the task must use await to go on with continuation. Thank you for your comments